# Oedipus/Electra complex and in-laws

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Does the Oedipus and Electra complex, which are often regarded as the reason why daughters are attached to their fathers more and the sons to the mothers, also explain why sons-in-law are not liked by the fathers and daughters-in-law are not liked by the mothers?

Is it because the sons and daughters-in-law are regarded as an challenge/barrier to their relationship with their sons and daughters?

Comment: Hi S. Welcome at CogSci. I believe those are separate things. Oedipus/Elektra complex are complexes ascribed to the child, not the parent. Parent's dislike towards sons/daughters in law is probably a way of trying to protect your offspring (which is I believe the main task of any parent).

Comment: Interesting insight. Thanks for answering!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no scientific basis for oedipus/electra complexes, and pseudoscience is off-topic here.